# How to random each loop item and on ajax / json data in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, random

How to random  each loop item and  on ajax / json data in jquery ?

data.json

```
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "title" : "new1",
      "content" : "content1"
    },
    {
      "title" : "new2",
      "content" : "content2"
    },
    {
      "title" : "new3",
      "content" : "content3"
    },
    {
      "title" : "new4",
      "content" : "content4"
    }
  ]
}
```

jquery ajax get json

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
              $.each(data.items, function(index,item) {
               var template = '<p>' + item.title + '</p>' + item.content + '<br />'; 

                  $('html').append(template);
                  return index < 1 ; // set 2 item 
              });

        }
     });
```

How to random  each loop item and  on ajax / json data in jquery ?

Comment: _"How to random each loop item"_ - Do you mean "How do I randomly sort/shuffle the `"items"` array?"

Comment: here you have leave one curly brasses } in the code. so may be this will be the error. and why you want to return the value. do you know the return will through you out of loop.

Comment: can you post actual json data ? this looks like hard coded.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes i meam How do I randomly sort/shuffle the "items" array with limit 2 item , thx help! update json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `'` and also close `.each()` add  `});` at the end of `.each()`

```
$.each(data.items, function(index,item) {
    var template = '<p>' + item.title + '</p>' + item.content + '<br />'; });
```

**For Random**

```
var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
var item = data[random_index];
```